# Drop database of Rails application from Ruby script, outside of application

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I need to run 'rake db:drop' console command from ruby script (outside of Rails app). Generally it looks simple:

```
system("cd /my/path && rake db:drop")
```

But the problem is I'm under rvm hell, and when I'm doing `cd /my/path` it doesn't load correct gemset and environment, that's why as result I have

```
Could not find activesupport-3.1.12 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems
```

Additionally, I have open connections problem, as Rails application is running.

How it could be done?
(my global task is to close existing connections to the database (we may have some, as I need to drop running rails app database), drop it, and then recreate again)

Thank you!

Comment: Why dont you call `rvm use @yourgemset`?

Comment: @JustinD. because correct environment for rvm itself will not be loaded anyway (e.g. no zsh/bach rc will be executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kill active connections, I use this in a rake task. That should take care of one problem.

```
task :kill_postgres_connections => :environment do
  db_name = "#{File.basename(Rails.root)}_#{Rails.env}"
  sh = <<EOF
ps xa \
  | grep postgres: \
  | grep #{db_name} \
  | grep -v grep \
  | awk '{print $1}' \
  | xargs kill
EOF
  puts `#{sh}`
end

task "db:drop" => :kill_postgres_connections
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little how it work? It kills only specific database connections, and other databases keep working?

Comment: Hi Leo, to summarise, it determines the database name by looking at the project root dir. Then it creates a local variable called `sh` which stores shell commands in the form of Ruby multiline comments: `<<EOF`. The commands search for and kill any db matching connections. The last line ensures that this task is run before `rake db:drop`. For more details read up on `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! The only question - i'm not sure, does it kill only the process related to database related to db_name? It means, if i have other databases running on the same server, it will not affect them?

Comment: Yes, that is true. It only kills db connections under that namespace.

Answer (score 1):

To drop PostgreSQL db in Rails 4 you can also patch ActiveRecord drop method. Based on https://www.krautcomputing.com/blog/2014/01/10/how-to-drop-your-postgres-database-with-rails-4/

```
# config/initializers/postgresql_database_tasks.rb

module ActiveRecord
  module Tasks
    class PostgreSQLDatabaseTasks

      def drop
        establish_master_connection
        connection.select_all "select pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='#{configuration['database']}' AND state='idle';"
        connection.drop_database configuration['database']
      end
    end
  end
end
```